# some issues with mouseenter and mouseleave functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function:

```
$(".insidediv").hide();

$(".floater").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".hideimg").fadeOut(function(){
        $(".insidediv").fadeIn();
    });
});

$(".floater").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".insidediv").fadeOut(function(){
        $(".hideimg").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

the function built to make a little animation, when you 'mouseenter' the div the picture I have there is hidden and than a few text show up.
it works fine if i move the mouse slowly. but if i move my mouse fast over the div the function getting confused or something and it shows me both '.insidediv and .hideimg,
how can i fixed that little problem so it wont show me both? thanks!

Comment: use `finish()` before calling `fadeOut` or `fadeIn` like `$(".hideimg").finish().fadeOut(..)`

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle with some code so as to let us have a better look at your question?

Comment: .stop() before the fadings .stop().fadeOut()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset the opacity, because `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` uses this css property for animation. Just stopping the animation is not enough.

This should work:

```
var inside = $(".insidediv"),
img = $(".hideimg");
duration = 500;

inside.hide();

$(".floater").mouseenter(function () {
    if (inside.is(":visible"))
        inside.stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, duration);
    img.stop().fadeOut(duration, function () {
        inside.fadeIn(duration);
    });
});

$(".floater").mouseleave(function () {
    if (img.is(":visible"))
        img.stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, duration);
    inside.stop().fadeOut(duration, function () {
        img.fadeIn(duration);
    });
});
```

I just introduced the `duration` variable to get animations of equal length.

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eau7M/1/ (modification from previous comment on other post)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var $insideDiv = $(".insidediv");
var $hideImg = $(".hideimg");
$insideDiv.hide();
$(".floater").mouseenter(function(){
    $hideImg.finish().fadeOut(function(){
        $insideDiv.fadeIn();
    });
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $insideDiv.finish().fadeOut(function(){
        $hideImg.fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Comment: same as i wrote to the upper guy, it is just stopping the animation but it doesnt reset it. so it makes the div just in lower opacity or something.. there is anyway i can "reset" it so it wont get the lower opacity ? thanks

Comment: we can use the jsfiddle the other guy used here : http://jsfiddle.net/KXbNM/    as you can see if you pass fast over the div he just stopped in the middle of the fading.

Comment: what modification do you need in this? this fiddles looks fine. do you want to fadeIn slow or slidle up/down?

Comment: no, this fiddle doesnt works fine. try to pass over the div in fast method not slowly. and you will see that the fading stop but it just stop where the fade stands. that mean the opacity or so just get lower but it doesnt back to the original path. how can i make that if i cross fast it stop the fading but return it to the original one.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your issue:

```
var inside = $(".insidediv"),
img = $(".hideimg");

inside.hide();

$(".floater").hover(function () {
img.stop(true).fadeOut('fast',function () {
    inside.stop(true).fadeIn('fast');
 });

},function () {
inside.stop(true).fadeOut('fast',function () {
    img.stop(true).fadeIn('fast');
});
});
```

Updated  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KXbNM/2/)

Comment: sorry for making you headache but it makes the same result.. try it by yourself in you fiddle.. move fast the mouse over the div and you will see the fading just stop and the opacity stay where the fade stopped.. Im using chrome.. mayb in other browsers it is different.. Do you have any idea what  I am talking about ? you guys seems not understand me

Comment: by the way as im trying to figure it out now. It seems the problem only happen on the first act ( mouseenter), in the second act it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the 'mouseleave' function when the mouse is still inside the
'floater' div.
Try this (i have tried it on the jsfiddle you setup and it works):

```
.....

<div class="floater">Float</div>
<div class="insidediv">inside</div>
<div class="hideimg">img</div>

var inside = $('.insidediv'),
img = $('.hideimg');

inside.hide();

$('.floater').mouseenter( function() {
  img.stop().hide();
inside.show( function() {
    $('.floater').mouseleave( function() {
      inside.hide();
        img.fadeIn();
        inside.stop();  // inside doesn't show when you hover the div many times fast
    });
  });
 });
 .....
```